# How to add "taskset" specifications in a VSCode debug .json file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Let us say, for example, how to consider the following command in a debug file `.vscode/.json`, to limit the allowed CPU list

```bash
taskset -c 13-25 python run.py --dir out/
```

I have tried, set args like:

```
"env": {"TASKSET": "..."},
"env": {"GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY": "..."}, 
        "prelaunchTask",
        "command": "taskset"`, etc.
```

Comment: what is `.vscode/.json`? I have never heard of this. Did you mean to say "tasks.json"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a launch-type launch config (I also tried experimenting with setting `"python": "taskset -c 13-25 ${command:python.interpreterPath}"` in the launch config, but that didn't work). You could try with an attach-type launch config. See [the VS Code user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_debugging-by-attaching-over-a-network-connection) for how to write a local Python script that uses the debugpy package to wait for a debug client (in this case, the VS Code debugger).

Ex. additions to your run.py:

> ```py
> import debugpy
>
> # 5678 is the default attach port in the VS Code debug configurations. Unless a host and port are specified, host defaults to 127.0.0.1
> debugpy.listen(5678)
> print("Waiting for debugger attach")
> debugpy.wait_for_client()
> debugpy.breakpoint()
> print('break on this line')
> ```

Launch config:

```json
{
    "name": "attach to run.py",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "connect": {
        "port": 5678
    },
    "justMyCode": true,
},
```

Then just run your command from the terminal (`taskset -c 13-25 python run.py --dir out/`), and then run the launch config.

I tried to see if I could make it more convenient by launching run.py with the `preLaunchTask` mechanism, but that didn't work because the launch won't start until the pre-launch task finishes... and debugpy would be waiting for the thing that is waiting for it ("deadlock").

---

Or you could go about this in the other way: Use a normal launch config with no taskset business whatsoever, put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the program, and once that breakpoint is hit, get the process ID of the Python process, and use `taskset -c -p 13-25 pid`.